HTTPS requests terminate after ~80 seconds with HTTP/2 but not with HTTP/1—only occurs in office environment with client-to-server connections
My team recently upgraded our application to use HTTP/2, and I’ve noticed that HTTPS requests between the client and server are terminating after around 80 seconds. This issue does not occur when using HTTP/1.
When I test this at home with HTTP/2, the requests stay open without any issues, so it seems to only happen in my office environment. Additionally, this problem is specific to client-to-server connections; server-to-server requests do not experience these terminations.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue, or could anyone provide insights on what might be causing this environment-specific behavior?

Please include the [mcve] that demonstrates the problem you're having.  We can't help you debug code we cannot see.

You need to look at the config of your server to confirm the timeout configuration for each HTTP version.
To look at the varied HTTP/2 behavior, you should look at the network path from the two different clients, they probably traverse different networks. At work, an internal network device is probably closing the connection.

what kind of internal network device can close the connection?
